# How to assign a constant value as default value in constructor

Tags: dart

```
class Foo {
  final int x;

  Foo([this.x = defValue]); // Compile-time error

  static get defValue => 10; 
}
```

Error:

> The default value of an optional parameter must be a constant.

`defValue` is a compile time constant, so I should be able to pass its value to the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `defValue` is not a compile-time constant expression. Evaluating it requires executing the getter to get a value, and constant evaluation cannot execute getters or methods (except a very specific list of allowed platform methods, like `int.operator+`). It might be that the expression returned by executing the `defValue` getter is itself a compile-time constant expression, but it's being returned through a non-constant operation.

Change the `defValue` definition to

```dart
 static const defValue = 10;
```

then it should work. Reading constant declarations is a compile-time constant operation.

You refer to the docs saying that you can use a static method as a compile-time constant. That is correct, but that's the *method itself* which is the constant, you are still not allowed to call it.
That is:

```dart
  static int foo(int x) => x;
  static const fooRef = foo; // valid!
```

works because referencing the `foo` function *value* is a constant expression.

A getter is not a method, and you cannot do a "tear-off" of the getter. When you refer to it, you need to execute its body, and that's not allowed in a constant context.

Comment: So, when docs say `You can use the static method as compile-time constant`, the word `use` here actually means `assign` and not `call`. Right sir? I wish you've written the docs.

Comment: Correct, the example after the sentence you quote shows using the function as a value. But do be careful what you wish for. The technical writers doing the language tour are top-notch, and while they might not be able to cite the verse and numbers of the spec for everything, they can write circles around us mere mortal word-hackers while keeping it all light, readable and understandable. Coding is easy, words are hard.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `defValue` is not known at compile time (since it's a getter and not a constant), so you should either use a constant variable like `static const int defValue = 10` or initialize the class like this:

```dart
class Foo {
  final int x;

  Foo([int x]) : this.x = x ?? defValue;

  static get defValue => 10; 
}
```

Comment: [Docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#class-variables-and-methods) says `You can use static methods as compile-time constants`